# Front Mission DS - UCS mission 1 tips?

Tags: nintendo-ds, front-mission

For the first USN mission, how do you survive through it?  The wanzers you start off with are so under-powered that they barely stand a chance 1-on-1 with the enemy wanzers, and along the way a mobile weapon shows up later.

It's understandable if it were a new game+ where you get at least the benefit of skills, but my "experienced" guys are total greenhorns.  What's the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since I played it so this info might be wrong, but you aren't supposed to win that battle by yourself, just survive long enough to power on the generator and then wait for your main strike team to come back out and take out the mobile weapon.  It would be nice if you managed to get in the last hit for the extra xp, but don't count on it.

I will double check this info once I get the chance.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like my Bravo team has to take out all the guys before Alpha team shows up, and then I get a few rounds to dance with the Prototype by myself until they come back out.  I realized it's much easier to survive if I wait until the lights are out, as they don't move to attack then.